# Selecting a Master Mode program on a Yamaha MotifXS (SysEx command) from an iPad app

Tags: midi, ipad

Anyone know of an iPad app that can send SysEx commands? The end result I'm looking for is this: I'd like to create a set list page where it would have the list of songs, and each song name is actually a button. Once pressed it would send the necessary SysEx command to choose a Master Mode Program in my Yamaha Motif synthesizer, - in this 'Master Mode', the Motif does not respond to normal Program Change messeges and requires SysEx commands.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this - but only through system exclusive messages, I have made it work using the iPad app Midi Designer, and the Line 6 Midi Mobilizer.

The system Ex command for Master change is `f0 43 10 7f 03 0a 00 00 xx f7`

`xx` is the master number from 1-128, but remember it will be master `-1` in hex, so master `A07` would be `06`, Master `C16` would be `2E` (not `2F`)

Hope this helps - note if you use MIDI Designer to leave off the `f0` at the start and the `f7` at the end of the string above